# String Manipulation and Formatting

Tags: json, datetime, nsstring

I am pulling a string using json that returns the estimated time in this format: "yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss-06:00"

I'm not sure how to go about getting rid of the unnecessary info. All i need is time in a format like this: hh:mm.

I am getting no output with this.

```
NSDate *date = [timeResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm"];
NSString* stringFromDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = stringFromDate;
```

UPDATE:
I found a hack to get it do work the date format was the problem. It kind of works if i use this as the date format: @"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ssz':'00".

Comment: BTW: that format is standard [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) with a timezone offset.

Comment: Before downvoting any question comment the reason for the same so the person who is asking question will understand his mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a hack to get it do work the date format was the problem. It kind of works if i use this as the date format: @"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ssz':'00".

Answer (score 1):

`NSDateFormatter` you need

```
NSDateFormatter *HHmm = [NSDateFormatter new];

NSString *format = @"HH:mm"; //If you want use 24H format 
NSString *format = @"hh:mm"; //If you want use 12H format 

[HHmm setDateFormat:format];
```

About formats you can read here - http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Of course if you want use not default locale `[NSLocale currentLocale]`

```
NSString *identifier = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:identifier];
[HHmm setLocale:locale];
```

(full list of identifiers you can find uses method `[NSLocale availableLocaleIdentifiers]`)

```
NSString *stringHHmm = [HHmm stringFromDate:NSDateObject]
```

Comment: No this is not completely correct. Your answer doesn't take locale into account.

Comment: Not sure what I'm doing wrong but I'm not getting any output. (Look at my edit)

Comment: What in your date object?

Comment: "stringFromDate" is always equal to NULL, but "date" is never empty.

Answer (score 1):

Store the value you got from parsing in the same format as it is, in a `NSDate` object and then format it using `stringFromDate` as you want.

```
    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    //set your format
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@""yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss-06:00""];
    [dateFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehaviorDefault];

    NSDate dateFrmParser = [dateFormatter dateFromString:<parsedDateString>];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm"];
    NSString* stringFromDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateFrmParser];
```